# Why is my meta reputation only synchronized every hour?

Tags: discussion, reputation, live-refresh

From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) it says this:

> Your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly)

Why is it synchronized every hour? Why not every minute, or instantly?

Comment: Counter-question - why synchronise every minute? Or instantly? What benefit is there that requires updates THAT FAST?

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The most likely answer is: because it's expensive to do so and the cost outweighs the benefit that one would get from this (one can already see his accurate reputation on the main site).

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is part of a smaller subset of sites which has millions of active users. Whatever you may think and know as a web developer, is not necessarily true for such sites. Even simple problems can be hard to impossible to solve when you're dealing with that amount of activity and throughput. It'd make an interesting book to be honest. Given how Stack Overflow is designed, I'm going to guess 50% of the book is going to be about caching strategies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because - it looks like 1 hour is good enough and any scheduled synchronization process (another example is revenge-downvote cleanup script) will have some period to run - one hour sounds like a reasonable compromise between resources spent on running the script (CPU time is not free) and benefits (from my point of view daily would be similarly ok).

In practical terms, there is not much impact of reputation for meta answers and really just several values of all possible SO reputations that are somewhat important for questions on meta (as these levels change guidance in answers):

- less than 5 - those can't post on meta except "ask about my question" - this is the only group that could benefit from less more frequent sync... but spending extra time on clarifying the question is not really harmful for the site.
- less than 50 - those users can't comment at arbitrary posts and as result need specific guidance.
- less than 2K - edits by those users must be reviewed and hence range of acceptable SO edits is a bit narrower
- more than 20K - those users can perform all possible moderations actions on SO and as result are hold to somewhat higher standards.

It is very unlikely that crossing one of these boundaries in the last hour would really matter for experience on meta.

What matters more is writing style and the author's attitude - a series of vegetable-themed accounts provided very good content for meta having just 5-10 reputation (just enough to post on meta). There are good posts by users with high reputation or moderators on other SE sites, but with just barely any points above the association bonus.